# Ajax call in javascript returns empty when the response is huge

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, websphere

Basically, I am trying to debug a code that was written long back by someone.

I have a jsp which is calling a javascript function on click of a button. In the javascript there is an ajax call happening to the Struts Action class. The Action class returns an Array List of objects to the jsp. My Array List has an inner list of objects too. Everything works fine when the list is small. But when the returned list is big, the ajax variable "data" returns as empty after a long time.

i think it is something to do with handling large data in the response. When i googled a few forums, i think the size of the response is exceeding a maximum limit and then returned as empty. When the response is small the variable "data" returns with a html reponse. But when it is huge, the variable has nothing.

Below is the ajax call. Since this is happening in production right now, any quick help is really appreciated. BTW, i am using Websphere 8.5.5.

```
function submitCriteria(submitSrc) {
    var nameOfFormToPost = "criteriaForm";
    var spanId = "resultDataSpan";
    var formAsString = getFormAsString(nameOfFormToPost, submitSrc);

    $.ajax({   
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',   
                url: "matchReconcileHome.do?execute=viewMatchResult",
                data: formAsString,   
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    idx = data.indexOf("<title>XXXXXXX- XXXXX - Login</title>");
                    if (idx > 0 && idx < 500) {
                        window.location = "/pdrWeb/Login.jsp";
                    }

                    //Split the text response into Span elements
                    spanElements = splitTextIntoSpan(data, spanId);

                    //Use these span elements to update the page
                    replaceExistingWithNewHtml(spanElements);

                    $("#matchResult").treeTable();

                    setPageNavigation();
                    setResultControls();
                    //alert("Ajax called back Done" );

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Problem with server response:\n " + textStatus + ", Error: " + errorThrown);
                }

            });   
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Debugging 101: any error indication in the browsers **developer** tools console or network tabs? In the network tab, what can you see in the **response** part for this request? anything?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, Thanks for quick response. I am new to browser debug dev tools. But hiwever, i tried printing the data variable to console using console.log(data). It prints correctly for small responses. But for larger ones, the cursor remains in the ajax call for a long time and then returns empty for "data" variable. I added debug statements in my jsp and all those jsp statements are printed correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that when the response is large and somehow becomes empty the `success` handler in your JS is still called, or does it trigger the `error` handler instead? How do you know `data` is empty? The code shown doesn't seem to test for that.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn, i added a console.log(data) just before the line "spanElements = splitTextIntoSpan(data, spanId);" and it prints nothing in the console.